# How to give bottom offset to Scaffold so that nothing (like bottom sheet, snackbar etc.) overlaps on the banner ad?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, admob, flutter-layout

One of the solutions that I tried was to wrap `Scaffold` in a custom `AdScaffold` Widget but it handled all the UI well enough but not the bottom sheet, FAB and snack bars.

Here is the code for `AdScaffold`

```
// Imports Here

class AdScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget body;
  final AppBar appBar;
  final Widget floatingActionButton;
  final FloatingActionButtonLocation floatingActionButtonLocation;
  final FloatingActionButtonAnimator floatingActionButtonAnimator;
  final List<Widget> persistentFooterButtons;
  final Widget drawer;
  final Widget endDrawer;
  final Widget bottomNavigationBar;
  final Widget bottomSheet;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final bool resizeToAvoidBottomPadding;
  final bool resizeToAvoidBottomInset;
  final bool primary;
  final DragStartBehavior drawerDragStartBehavior;
  final bool extendBody;
  final Color drawerScrimColor;

  const AdScaffold({
    Key key,
    this.appBar,
    @required this.body,
    this.floatingActionButton,
    this.floatingActionButtonLocation,
    this.floatingActionButtonAnimator,
    this.persistentFooterButtons,
    this.drawer,
    this.endDrawer,
    this.bottomNavigationBar,
    this.bottomSheet,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.resizeToAvoidBottomPadding,
    this.resizeToAvoidBottomInset,
    this.primary = true,
    this.drawerDragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.start,
    this.extendBody = false,
    this.drawerScrimColor,
  })  : assert(primary != null),
        assert(extendBody != null),
        assert(drawerDragStartBehavior != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final adService = Provider.of<AdService>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      key: key,
      appBar: appBar,
      floatingActionButton: floatingActionButton,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: floatingActionButtonLocation,
      floatingActionButtonAnimator: floatingActionButtonAnimator,
      persistentFooterButtons: persistentFooterButtons,
      drawer: drawer,
      endDrawer: endDrawer,
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
      bottomSheet: bottomSheet,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: resizeToAvoidBottomInset,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: resizeToAvoidBottomPadding,
      primary: primary,
      drawerDragStartBehavior: drawerDragStartBehavior,
      extendBody: extendBody,
      drawerScrimColor: drawerScrimColor,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60), child: body),
          adService.source != null && adService.source == AdSource.facebook
              ? Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: 60,
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: FacebookBannerAd(
                        placementId: AppConfig.facebookPlacementId,
                        bannerSize: BannerSize.STANDARD,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : SizedBox()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have resolved this by using the `persistentFooterButtons` parameter in `Scaffold`.

```
persistentFooterButtons: _isAdDisplayed
   ? <Widget>[
      Container(
         height: 50
      )
   ]
   : null,
```

`_isAdDisplayed` is a boolean attribute of my `Statefull widget` that I init to false (into the `initState()` method) and I update when my banner is loaded.

```
BannerAd _createBannerAd() {
   return BannerAd(
      adUnitId: AD_MOB_HOME_BANNER_ID,
      size: AdSize.smartBanner,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
         if (event == MobileAdEvent.loaded) {
            setState(() {
               _isAdDisplayed = true;
            });
         } else if (event == MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
            setState(() {
               _isAdDisplayed = false;
            });
         }
      },
   );
}
```

I did not check if it works for SnackBar and BottomSheet, but it works for FAB.

My answer is well inspired from https://cogitas.net/show-firebase-admob-banner-ad-in-flutter/

Comment: @KushagraSaxena, did you find a good solution to this issue ? I am still working with the solution above but it is absolutely not perfect, so if you found an other solution, I am interested.